# Min of exponential distr

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ be independent random variables, where each of them follows an exponential distribution. What distribution has $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2, \ldots,X_n\}$ ?

Attempt: We have a formula for how to find the CDF, F_Y(y) but then I would know whether to put $e^{-\lambda y}$ or $e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+...\lambda_n) y}$ so I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
P(Y>x)=P(X_1>x,X_2>x,\ldots,X_n>x).
$$

Comment: So, first try to find CDF and the derive to get PDF?

Comment: You can probably recognize the distribution from the CDF alone.